# How to prevent a dark edge with transparency using montage?

Tags: imagemagick, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to montage some semi-transparent icons into one image using imagemagicks montage tool.

Unfortunately, after every operation with alpha a bit of black is showing everywhere on anti-aliased edges.

For example, these two icons:

[image: icon 1]
and
[image: icon 2]

After issuing

```
montage 1.png 2.png -background none montage.png
```

Result in:

[image: montaged 1 and 2]

I've tried numerous combinations of alpha, background and changing option order and haven't found a way to prevent this. Any idea?

My system is windows 8.1+cygwin, montage version is:

> $ montage -version
>   Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-3 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-01
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: DPC OpenMP
>   Delegates (built-in): autotrace bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype
>   fpx gslib jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib

Comment: Works fine on ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 and also using `convert 1.png 2.png +append 3.png`

Comment: Checked using  ImageMagick 6.9.2-3 Q16 x64 2015-09-19 static - it works  there too. Yep, this is a version specific bug. Thanks, @MarkSetchell, post this as an answer so i can accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a version-specific bug, as the given command works fine on `ImageMagick 6.9.1-10` and also using:

```
convert 1.png 2.png +append 3.png
```